# Retrieving email-id from database and send mail to them

Tags: yii, extension-methods, mailer

In yii i am creating sendemail functionality. I am using mailer extension and its working correctly after making all settings of SMTP. i had made method actionEmail in controller as-

```
public function actionEmail()
{
    $model=new User;
    $mailer = Yii::createComponent('application.extensions.mailer.EMailer');
    $mailer->IsSMTP();
    $mailer->IsHTML(true);
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mailer->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mailer->Port = 465;
    $mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mailer->Username = "abc@gmail.com";
    $mailer->Password = "abc";
    $mailer->From = "xyz@gmail.com";
    $mailer->FromName = "Balaee.com";
    $mailer->AddAddress('shilpa.kirad@shailani.com');
    $mailer->Subject = "welcome to Balaee";
    $mailer->IsHTML(true);
    //  $html = $this->renderPartial('myview',array('content'=>'Hello World'),true);
```

$mailer->Body = "

## Welcome

click on link for other detail ".$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

```
    if($mailer->Send()) {
        echo "Please check mail";
        //Yii::app()->user->setFlash('register','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
        //  $this->refresh();
    }
    else {
        echo "Fail to send your message!";
    }
}
```

This method is implementing correctly.It is sending mail to address which is mentioned in mailer->AddAdress.But now i want to retrive email id's from database corresponding to specific user's id and send mail to him. i.e.I dont want to insert hard coded value for this field. So how can i do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for fetch use id of user to get email address as

```
$user_model=User::model()->findByPk($id);
```

and set in email as

```
$mailer->AddAddress($user_model->email_id);
```

where id and email_id are the table column name.
check other ways .
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao

Comment: Sir thanx for reply...i had made changes as u told. but its giving an error as-Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: check if $user_model is set or not.check the database if value exist related to given $id .

Comment: i had tried it by passing hard coded value of id as 1. but still its giving same error.

Comment: check you define any column as primary key and that have the value as 1

Comment: yaa sir its working.....Actully i was not having any record with value as 1. Thanx for help

Answer (score 0):

For this to be done, you can fetch email id from database using following query:

```
  $email = SELECT email FROM USER WHERE user_id = "X";
```

Here X is user_id of user whom you want to send email.

And provide this `$email` in the receipient's email field. Thanks.